# Lattice vectors calculation

Tags: crystal-structure

How can I find the crystal lattice vectors, given the crystal parameters?
For example, consider a crystal of rhombohedral symmetry, where a=b and c are known, and alpha=beta=90, gamma=120. How can the lattice vectors be found?

Comment: That's hexagonal, not rhombohedral.

Answer (score 2):

You can find this using elementary geometry. Also, since the unit cell may be positioned in different ways with respect to the coordinate system, there can be many different answers, all equally valid.

One possible answer implies alignment of the cell vectors $\vec a$ and $\vec c$ with the coordinate axes X and Z, which leads to the following:
$$\left\{\begin{align}
\vec{\bf a} =& \Big(|a|,0,0\Big)\\
\vec{\bf b} =& \left(-{1\over2}|a|,{\sqrt3\over2}|a|,0\right)\\
\vec{\bf c} =& \Big(0,0,|c|\Big)
\end{align}\right.
$$

Answer (score 2):

A lattice vector can be defined as $\bar V= u\bar a+ v\bar b+ w\bar c$ where $u,\;v,\;w$ are integers describing the next lattice point out from the origin (at $[0,0,0]$) with position $[ua, \;vb, \; wc]$ and other lattice points are at $[nua, \;nvb, \; nwc]$ for integer $n$. The base vectors of the lattice are $\bar a, \bar b,\bar c$

Notes:

Conventionally $[u \;v \; w]$ is used to define a lattice vector as a set of parallel point rows whereas  round brackets $(h \;k \; l)$ describes the Miller indices that define parallel planes  satisfying the equation $hx/a+ky/b+lz/c=n$ where $n$ is an integer.

A lattice is formally defined as 'an array of points in space such that each lattice point has exactly the same environment in the same orientation'.